# php.net's PHP opening tag

Tags: php, c++

In, for example, http://php.net/source.php?url=/include/prepend.inc, the opening PHP tag used looks like this: `<?php // -*- C++ -*-` (not just `<?php`).

What does that mean, and what's C++ got to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some editors see the `-*- C++ -*-` part, and enable C++ syntax for the file. It has nothing to do with PHP, and indeed is commented out so PHP will skip it.